# What does `uicache` command do on jailbreak iphone?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I use the command Whenever I install a jailbreak app and the app's icon doesn't show up.  What are some of the command's other use cases? What's the mechanism behind the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpringBoard (the "home screen" application) keeps a cache of all app icons. When installing or removing apps from the App Store, `installd` performs those changes and updates that cache to reflect them. When installing apps by other means (such as through Cydia), `installd` is not involved in any way, so for the app to show up properly on the home screen, the cache has to be updated "manually" somehow.
That is exactly what `uicache` was designed to do. How exactly it achieves that varies between iOS version, but it's mostly a combination of removing the cache files, killing/reloading the services dealing with them and iterating over the installed applications to build a new cache.

You can check its source code [on saurik's git repo](http://gitweb.saurik.com/uikittools.git/blob/HEAD:/uicache.mm).